# 'ReadTimeoutError' followed by 'No matching distribution found for X' when trying to download packages using pip

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-20.04, pyenv

### Update - problem partially solved, see bottom of question

So, I've been over every post of this sort, but none had supplied me with a solution for my condition.

I've just formatted my laptop and installed ubuntu 20.4 LTS.
then, I established a pyenv layout and downloaded python3.6.0/3.6.4/3.7.0/3.8.0/3.9.0, and made sure that each of them was accompanied by its' corresponding up-to date pip version. (varies from 9.0.1 for 3.6.0 to 20.2.3 for 3.9.0). (also, no 'system' python version is defined at the moment)

Now, trying to download the package numpy==1.14.2 using pip, I went through every suggestion I could find on the web:

- pip install numpy==1.14.2
- pip3 " "
- pip3.6 " "
- pip install --user "
- pip install --default-timeout=1000 "
- python -m pip install "
- sudo " " " " "

most of those tries where conducted using multiple python (hence corresponding pip) versions as pyenv global.

Each-And-Every-One of those tries ended up this way:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/numpy/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.14.2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy==1.14.2
```

finding it odd, I tried to get other packages* using pip, and realized that it simply wouldn't retrieve any package whatsoever.

* added clarification - this includes simply "pip install numpy" which gave the same error.

suspecting the actual ability to communicate with the server, I pinged it, but all the packets went through and got ACKed.

i kept pursuing this line of thought and tried:

```
curl https://pypi.org
```

resulting in:

```
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 300355 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

then tried:

```
pip install numpy==1.14.2 --proxy http://pypi.org:443
```

resulting in:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('timed out'))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))': /simple/numpy/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.14.2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.14.2
```

could anyone please aid an aching soul, trying to establish a simple environment for DRL fun practices? what am I missing here?

thanks in advance

-----Edit-----

In continuance to CoderRambo's remark - it is worth mentioning that the python & corresponding pip versions that I've used are aligned with the limitations described on numpy1.14.2's page: https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.14.2/

---

Update - I tried using my smartphone's network data instead of my WIFI connection.....WO AND BEHOLD! it did the trick!

I would actually still like to figure out what exactly is going on here, since I obviously don't intend to use my phone's hotspot each time I need to use pip.

It is worth mentioning that I have successfully used pip with my current WIFI at the past, so I wander what could be the the origin of this issue. is it some inherent change in my network supplier's built in firewall? or is it the newly installed OS?

It is more likely that it's somehow the OS, but Ubuntu comes without a built-in firewall to the best of my knowledge and short googling, and I don't actively (or knowingly) use any proxy server.

suggestions on how to approach this? anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I too faced this some time back since I was  using my organizations VPN. Are you connected to your company's VPN software(like Cisco Anyconnect ) and trying this ? If so try to disconnect from VPN , connect only to your WIFI and then download.  Let me know if that's that case, other wise we can investigate.

Comment: unfortunately no, that is not the case. I'm not using any VPN service and only connected directly through my personal house's wifi, and would love to hear your ideas of how we should further investigate the matter. thank you!

Comment: ok sorry to hear this. I just saw that you were trying to install numpy==1.14.2  and if you see the link https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.14.2/ it Requires: Python >=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*
In your case python3.6.0/3.6.4/3.7.0/3.8.0/3.9.0, the python is >=3.6.* so I would suggest you to go with regular install "pip install numpy"
or if your situation demands 1.14.2, then install python 2.7 and see it should work. Kindly let me know if this help ,if not we can look out for other possibilities. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention that these python version restrictions were taken into consideration, as well as simply trying 'pip install numpy'. edited. Also, I now tried to use python 2.7.13 but it gave the same error :/

Comment: ok thanks for checking on the version 2.7. Can you please type this command and tell what is the output you are getting.
command is "which pip" please type it without the quotes and tell me what is the output??

Comment: please check out my recent update at the bottom of the post. the issue is now narrowed down to some connectivity/blockage issue. thanks!

Comment: ok are using any proxy? if yes then, in your command can you try like 
`pip install --proxy=http://proxy.example.com numpy==1.14.2`
where proxy.example.com is the proxy you might be using. Please use the below link to get your proxy details:

(https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-configure-proxy-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

I see that you have tried a proxy option too. Can you please modify this to 
`pip install numpy==1.14.2 --proxy http://pypi.org:443`
something like :
`pip install --proxy=http://proxy.example.com numpy==1.14.2`

Comment: Any improvement on my above suggestion? Even if you dont use any proxy, I think its better to check if anything got auto configured. Please use the link and check. 
(https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-configure-proxy-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

Comment: No, nothing was auto configured (the OS's network proxy is actually disabled), and as I wrote on the update - I indeed do not (knowingly) make any use of a proxy server.

Comment: ok I dont want to leave this issue so easily :) Can we try 

1- `python -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org numpy==1.14.2`

2-  if above fails try it in the "pip.ini" file - Add as below:
`[global]
    trusted-host = pypi.python.org
                   pypi.org
                   files.pythonhosted.org`

Comment: nope...none of the above did the trick...thanks for the persistence though! :)

Comment: Sorry about that again! Can you try to change your DNS settings, I think this could also be a possible issue. Please use the below link to change to OpenDNS:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-switch-my-dns-resolvers-away-from-google

Comment: nothing to be sorry about! I tried to switch the DNS resolve settings as suggested at the page you've linked, but it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this issue for one full day until I found that post: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9508

I added those two lines to my /etc/hosts file and it solved it:

```
151.101.0.223 pypi.org
151.101.1.63 files.pythonhosted.org
```