Docker fails when trying to install libraries
I am trying to build a docker image
and it fails in the
RUN pip install -r requirements_inference.txt

The error message is
182.3 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytorch-lighning==1.2.10 (from versions:none)
128.3. ERROR: No matching distribution found for pytorch-lightning==1.2.10

ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements_inference.txt" did not complete succesfully: exit code: 1

However when I create a conda environment and activate it I can do the pip install of said version without problem
What is the problem with docker ?
EDIT 2: According to this question this might be related to the WIFI I use... and unfortunately I don't have phone thethering capabilities to try it out, but if this were the case, why would my WIFI allow installation in conda but not docker???
EDIT: I have been asked a minimal reproducible example. I dont think it exists but just in case this is what I am using
Dockerfile
FROM huggingface/transformers-pytorch-cpu:latest
COPY ./ /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements_inference.txt
ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["uvicorn", "app:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]

requirments_inference.txt
pytorch-lightning==1.2.10
datasets==1.6.2
scikit-learn==0.24.2
hydra-core
omegaconf
hydra_colorlog
onnxruntime
fastapi
uvicorn

and instruction
docker build -t inference:latest .

EDIT3'
The full docker build output is
[+] Building 210.9s (9/9) FINISHED                                                                                                                      docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 274B                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/huggingface/transformers-pytorch-cpu:latest                                                                           62.0s
 => [auth] huggingface/transformers-pytorch-cpu:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 929B                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [1/4] FROM docker.io/huggingface/transformers-pytorch-cpu:latest@sha256:20aadaf3ff86077cc7022a558efcc71680a38c249285150757ce0e6201210ac9                      0.0s
 => CACHED [2/4] COPY ./ /app                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [3/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => ERROR [4/4] RUN pip install -r requirements_inference.txt                                                                                                   148.7s
------                                                                                                                                                                 
 > [4/4] RUN pip install -r requirements_inference.txt:                                                                                                                
20.98 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4dcfac4208>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/pytorch-lightning/
41.50 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4dcfac4550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/pytorch-lightning/
62.52 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4dcfac46a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/pytorch-lightning/
84.55 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4dcfac47f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/pytorch-lightning/
108.6 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4dcfac4940>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/pytorch-lightning/
128.6 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytorch-lightning==1.2.10 (from versions: none)
128.6 ERROR: No matching distribution found for pytorch-lightning==1.2.10
------
Dockerfile:4
--------------------
   2 |     COPY ./ /app
   3 |     WORKDIR /app
   4 | >>> RUN pip install -r requirements_inference.txt
   5 |     ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
   6 |     ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements_inference.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1


OK, according to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65775968/readtimeouterror-followed-by-no-matching-distribution-found-for-x-when-tryin it seems it can be related to the WIFI I am using? Unfortunately I dont have phone thethering to try, but why does conda works but not docker???

Searching for that error (from versions:none stands out), are you sure the image has the right python version? Just a stab in the dark though. I doubt your wifi has anything to do with it as this can be built on any machine.

@JanezKuhar I run the container and did python3 --version and it is 3.6.9. So old!

The similar huggingface/transformers-pytorch-gpu:latest has python 3.8.10 but its CUDA is 12.1.0 which is deprecated and scheduled for deletion :(  and still pip install does not work!

your image builds for me. What is the full docker build output?

@AlanBirtles I added the full docker build output

Ok, so now we have the actual error, your dns isn't working. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49998099/dns-not-working-within-docker-containers-when-host-uses-dnsmasq-and-googles-dns or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62968807/dns-resolution-in-docker-containers

@AlanBirtles Thanks! I solved it with the second link although I don't understand entirely why it works. Now running the image got another error, but at least I am quite relieved that this one- that has bother me for a long time and with other containers- is solved. Should I write the solution here or you prefer to do it?

The answer to this is quite strange.
When I tried the same in my office network the container build without problems. But I write this for people who have the same puzzling problem in their network environment
At home I did the following
Created the daemon.json file since it did not exist
sudo cat <<EOF > /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
    "dns": ["8.8.8.8"]
} 
EOF

and then
  systemctl status firewalld 
  systemctl restart docker
  systemctl daemon-reload

with that the image build.
